# Convergence of $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(3n\right)^2}{\sqrt{\left(16n^2+5n+1\right)^{n+1}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Study the convergence of $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(3n\right)^2}{\sqrt{\left(16n^2+5n+1\right)^{n+1}}}$

Ratio test seemed like the best bet here, but it yields me a rather uncomfortable limit to solve. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: The root test seems like a more natural choice here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is with *equivalence:* 
$$\sqrt{\left(16n^2+5n+1\right)^{n+1}}\sim_\infty(16n^2)^{\tfrac{n+1}2}=(4n)^{n+1}$$
hence
$$\frac{3n^2}{\sqrt{\left(16n^2+5n+1\right)^{n+1}}}\sim_\infty\frac{3n^2}{(4n)^{n+1}}=\frac{3}{4^{n+1}n^{n-1}}=o\Bigl(\frac1{4^n}\Bigl),$$
which converges.

Comment: Uhm, not sure I understand/am familiar with some of the stuff you wrote there. :(

Comment: Thuis supposes you heard about the notion of `equivalence` and $o/O$ notation. Roughly, $f(n)\sim_\infty g(n)$ lmeans $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\lvert f(n)\rvert}{\lvert g(n)\rvert}=1$. It's a powerful method that allows to remove the irrelevant details/ calculations. Similarly, $f(n)=_{\infty}g(n)$ means the same ration tends  to $0$. The main result is that two equivalent sequences with positive terms both converge or both diverge.

Answer (score 0):

Since for $n>3$:
$$
(16n^2+5n+1)^{n+1}>(16n^2)^{n+1}\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
 \frac{1}{(4n)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(16n^2)^{n+1}}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{(16n^2+5n+1)^{n+1}}}\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
 \frac{3n^2}{(4n)^{n+1}}>\frac{3n^2}{\sqrt{(16n^2+5n+1)^{n+1}}}
$$
Thus:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{3}\frac{3n^2}{\sqrt{(16n^2+5n+1)^{n+1}}}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{3n^2}{\sqrt{(16n^2+5n+1)^{n+1}}}<
$$
$c:=\sum_{n=0}^{3}\frac{3n^2}{\sqrt{(16n^2+5n+1)^{n+1}}}$
$$
c+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{3n^2}{{(4n)^{n-1}\cdot 16n^2}}<c+\frac{3}{256}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n^2}}\leq c+\frac{3}{256}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)n}=
$$
Here use that $(4n)^{n-1}\geq (4n)^2$ if $n>3$
$$
=c+\frac{3}{256}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)}-\frac{1}{n}=c+\frac{3}{512}<\infty
$$